# Push Notification UNNotificationCategory identifier addition limit

Tags: ios, swift, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I'm adding as follows in all categories, but when I add more than 100, the first 100 category id work and the rest are not working.

```
func setNotificationCategories(application: UIApplication) {

    let center: UNUserNotificationCenter = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
    center.delegate = self
    center.requestAuthorization(options: [.sound, .alert, .badge]) { _, error in

        if error != nil {
            return
        }

        var notificationCategories: Set<UNNotificationCategory> = []

        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "NotificationCategories", ofType: "plist"),
           let notificationCategoriesArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String: Any]] {

            for item in notificationCategoriesArray {

                if let categoryId = item["CategoryId"] as? String,
                   let buttonText = item["ButtonText"] as? String {

                    let notificationActions = [UNNotificationAction(identifier: "1", title: firstButtonText, options: [.foreground,
                                                                                                                      .authenticationRequired])]

                    let notificationCategory: UNNotificationCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: categoryId,
                                                                                              actions: notificationActions,
                                                                                              intentIdentifiers: [],
                                                                                              options: .customDismissAction)
                    notificationCategories.insert(notificationCategory)
                }
            }
        }
        center.setNotificationCategories(notificationCategories)
        self.getNotificationSettings()
    }
}
```

Sample plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">

<plist version="1.0">
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CategoryId</key>
        <string>1</string>
        <key>ButtonText</key>
        <string>check!</string>
    </dict>
    <dict>
        <key>CategoryId</key>
        <string>2</string>
        <key>ButtonText</key>
        <string>approve</string>
    </dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

I couldn't find any information about this when I looked through the apple documentation. Is it possible to add more than 100 categories?